# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError at java.util.ArrayList.add

Tags: android

I am using the following code for reading items from an XML file:

```
try {
            InputStream istream = assetManager.open("files/Items.xml");
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = builder.parse(istream);
            doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
            NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("Item");
            System.out.println();
            for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
                Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
                if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                    Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
                    String name = getTagValue("Name", eElement);
                    String family = getTagValue("Family", eElement);
                    _shahidViewModels.add(new ShahidViewModel(
                            name,
                            family
                    ));
                }
            }
            istream.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The following error occurs:

```
2109-2109/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
            at java.util.ArrayList.add(ArrayList.java:114)
            at addpt.ResultSearchActivity.fillData(ResultSearchActivity.java:76)
            at addpt.ResultSearchActivity.onCreate(ResultSearchActivity.java:54)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

What does this error mean?
And how do I solve this problem?

build.gradle:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.1"
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ad.dp.t"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}
```

Please provide me with a solution. I do not have any ideas to solve this problem

The number of records in items.xml was: 150000 record

Comment: use a pull/sax xml parser

Comment: You are running out of memory due to the large amount of data

Comment: `150000 record` thats a lot of data.

Answer (score 0):

Its not a good way to pull all 1000 of rows once and for all, introduce your custom xml parsing pagination or use third party if any. 
Load 50 items from your file and if user want to load more data than load next 50 items also override outofMemory in your activity or fragment for safe side, but best approach should be like says if your list contains more than 200 items than remove 1st 50 items and than add new items so you will maintain max 200 items in your list, other safe checks like start or end of file, list size should be consider by doing this you will not get out of memory exception

Comment: Thanks, I was getting an error and I know why I'm getting now.